# How to enable SSH in Raspberry Pi and connect through Putty?

Tags: ssh

How to enable SSH in Raspberry Pi and connect through Putty ?

Comment: What did you try? Have you looked at Google results?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Assuming a recent Raspbian that dupe should get you up to speed. If it - for whatever reaseon - it does not let es know. Add helpful details to your question for reopening though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know your Raspberry Pi's IP Address (use a tool, for example, http://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/br/). 
If you are using raspberry pi 3, I think you need to create a blank file name "ssh" in your SD card boot folder to enable ssh connection.
And then try to connect, open Putty, fill in the IP address in host name, select a port, connection type=ssh, and click "Open".

It will probably ask you for a name and password, the default is:
user: pi, password: raspberry